# Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql

i need help from you guys.
I am using oracle apex for university, and my task is to create triggers. I'm struggling a lot creating them, I don't even know what is wrong with this trigger. Can someone help me?

I get error

```
Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date <a string literal with character set specification> <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification> <an alternat
Error at line 3: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'
Error at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at for in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between group having intersect minus order start union where connect || indicator multiset member submultiset
Error at line 3: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'CONTRACT' Error at line 3: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'CONTRACT'   -
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER restrict_orders
    BEFORE INSERT ON orders
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        DECLARE countOrders number;
        set countOrders := SELECT count(contract) FROM orders WHERE :new:contract := old:contract AND (:old.status := 'PREPARING' OR :old.status := 'IN PROGRESS');
            IF (countOrders :> 3)
            THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20202, 'You have too much active orders.');
            END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few errors; see if this helps.

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * From orders;

  CONTRACT STATUS
---------- ---------
         1 PREPARING
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER restrict_orders
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON orders
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5    countOrders number;
  6  BEGIN
  7    SELECT count(contract)
  8      INTO countOrders
  9      FROM orders
 10      WHERE contract = :new.contract
 11        AND status IN ('PREPARING', 'IN PROGRESS');
 12
 13    IF countOrders > 3 THEN
 14       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20202, 'You have too many active orders.');
 15    END IF;
 16  END;
 17  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into orders (contract, status) values (1, 'PREPARING');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into orders (contract, status) values (1, 'PREPARING');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into orders (contract, status) values (1, 'PREPARING');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into orders (contract, status) values (1, 'PREPARING');
insert into orders (contract, status) values (1, 'PREPARING')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20202: You have too many active orders.
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.RESTRICT_ORDERS", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.RESTRICT_ORDERS'
```

Kind of *works*. **However**, note that it'll fail if you attempt to insert more than a single row at a time because table will be *mutating* (so you'd have to take another, more complex approach), but - if you'll insert just one row at a time, you're good:

```
SQL> insert into orders (contract, status)
  2  select 1, 'PREPARING'   from dual union all
  3  select 2, 'IN PROGRESS' from dual;
insert into orders (contract, status)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.ORDERS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.RESTRICT_ORDERS", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.RESTRICT_ORDERS'


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked. I'm just going to insert rows one by one, I think this will work for me :) I just have a form, which you fill and then INSERT happens

Comment: You're welcome. If that's a form, then yes - it'll be row-by-row. Even better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your syntax which should be -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER restrict_orders
BEFORE INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE countOrders number;
BEGIN
     SELECT count(contract)
       INTO countOrders
       FROM orders
      WHERE :new.contract = :old.contract 
        AND :old.status IN ('PREPARING', 'IN PROGRESS');

     IF (countOrders >= 3) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20202, 'You have too much active orders.');
     END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It still doesn't works. Getting error Error at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue. bad bind variable 'NEW' Error at line 6: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / >  at for in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between group...

Comment: @ManTas, You need to take declare out of begin block. Try the edited version.

Comment: I have tried, but also getting error.
Error at line 6: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW' Error at line 6: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'CONTRACT' Error at line 3: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator Error at line 6: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'CONTRACT'

Comment: @ManTas, try the updated version now.

Comment: You have misstyped, here should be dot between 'new' and contract. But now got error: Error at line 3: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name